# How to find out primary keys of a table in android sqlite programatically?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been working on an application where I need to determine the primary keys of the table programatically. Is there any API exposed in Android Sqlite which enables us to do this? I was able to find an [API](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/table_column_metadata.html) for retrieving primary keys of a table in C, but couldn't find the same for Android.

Any leads would be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pragma table_info(table_name)
```

Run this schema (query) and find where pk value is 1